# Delete ca certificate not working?

Tags: java, security, ssl, certificates

I have added a root ca in my ubuntu machine by using the following commands:

```
mkdir  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/custom/
mv myserver.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/custom/
update-ca-certificates
```

This works as intended, the cacert file in `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` (linked from the java installation folder) is correctly updated by the `ca-certificates-java` package.
However when I remove the file, and rerun the update command, it returns "0 certificates removed".

```
> rm myserver.crt
> sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
```

And it is still in the java cacerts file:

```
echo 'changeit' | keytool -list -v -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts | grep 'Owner:'  | grep myserver
```

Using `update-ca-certificates -f` doesn't help.

So how to remove a ca certificate in ubuntu, and make sure it is also deleted in the java key store ?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. Same issue. Any solution yet?